# Branching modifies code in GIT repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Our GIT repo has ended up in a weird state. If I branch off the develop branch, and immediately diff the new branch with develop, they differ. The new branch contains an old bug which has been fixed in the develop branch. This is all done locally using SourceTree and the latest develop branch from remote repo. My teammate experienced the same thing, so it can't be just my local repo being corrupt. How is this possible, and what could be done to fix it?

Comment: Just speculating... Is it possible that maybe you branched from your local `develop` branch, but you forgot to pull before creating the new branch, thus making the `new_branch` different from the remote `develop` branch. And if you made a pull afterwards, maybe the local `develop` branch was updated to the state of the remote `develop` branch?
Otherwise, maybe you made did your `git diff` command incorrectly and included changes in the work-tree or the index in the diff?

Comment: You should try doing `git branch new_branch develop` and then do `git rev-parse new_branch` and `git rev-parse develop`? Are those two commit hashes really different?

Comment: @Alderath: No they are identical. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If those are identical, that means that the two branches are identical. So it probably means your `git diff` command is issued incorrectly (ie. you think you are diffing the two branches, but you're not).

Answer (score 0):

Your local repository is probably "compromised". Clone it (in another folder) and checkout the develop branch to see if they still differ.

Comment: My teammate experienced the same thing, so it can't be just my local repo being corrupt.